# Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "L 1214.5 85 L 86…". in Highcharts-3d

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm using https://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-area-multiple this chart in reactjs here in this [Template](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9xg4vv?file=index.js)

Facing this below error while loading area chart using highcharts-3d as I'm unable to find the solution asking here[image]

Looking for some help/suggessions.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you recreate this problem on this [template](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vz2zqa?file=index.js), where you put the `d` path? I need to see it on the code instead error to check.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus Thanks for quick reply.
It was not there in my code there is dsetter function inside highcharts.js file from there I'm getting this error In the above template I'm unable to save the code. Could u pls guide me in that?

Comment: You ought to recreate this, If you want to publish your changing in a template, fork project in your stackblitz account, or another online code editor, showing your case.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus I have recreated it and edited in the above question and added template there could you pls check.

Comment: This error looks like a regression bug, on version 10.1.0 is not showing, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aynwz3xj/);

Comment: @SebastianHajdus Thank you so much. It's working without any error in version 10.1.0

Comment: You can follow this ticket on [GH](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18040).